# Parametric equation of straight line through antipodal points on a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $N=2$ and let $u, -u$ two antipodal points on the sphere. My question is: what is the parametric equation of the straight line through the sphere joining $u$ and $v$?

I was thinking something like
$$tu+(1-t)(-u), \quad t\in[0, 1],$$
where for $t=1$ I have $u$ and for $t=0$ I have $-u$. Does my reasoning hold true? I guess no because I didn't use the information that they are antipodal points in the sphere.

I hope you could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are “podal points”? Do you mean [“antipodal”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point)?

Comment: I mean diametrically opposite points.

Comment: Yes, your line starts at $-u$ and ends in $u$.  You man simplify the equation to $u(2t-1)$.  Starting in $u$ gives $u(1-2t)$.

Comment: @User1010 those are antipodes then.  "Podal" means "of or pertaining to the foot"; it's the anti- that gives the meaning of opposite

Comment: @postmortes thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe the fact the points are on the sphere is "hidden" here?

Comment: It's irrelevant.  It's an equation of the line joining $u$ and $-u$.